# PendingIntent continues to fire on activity reload

Tags: android, android-activity, reload, android-pendingintent

I have a PendingIntent firing on click on a notification that basically send an intent to my main menu (which is set to singleTop launch mode). This fires the onNewIntent which then loads the data I want and goes to another activity with that data loaded. Unfortunately onNewIntent does not work if the application is currently closed so I had to put a call to onNewIntent from onCreate and include a check in then onNewIntent.

Everything works splendidly except now after you fire your notification the pendingIntent seems to be happy with firing every single time onCreate is called, it doesn't go away. I am not sure how to throw in a check or even clear the pending intent after a use. My code is as follows:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null && extras.containsKey("notification")) {
        if(extras.getBoolean("notification", false)) {
            loadData(extras.getString("data"));
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, OtherClass.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}

//Code snippet of notification setup
notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Notification Reminder", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
contentTitle = "Notification_Title";
bundle.putBoolean("notification", true);
bundle.putString("data", contentTitle.toString());
notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                            notificationIntent.setData((Uri.parse("application://"+SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())));

contentTitle = contentTitle + " click me!";
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, notificationText, contentIntent);
```

Comment: I fixed this issue by firing off a new Intent to my MainMenu. This seems kind of hackish but it works for the activity I wanted, loading the data I hoped for, and leaving it open when user returns to the main menu with the back button. My modified onNewIntent just has a "startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenu.class));" right before the startActivity(myIntent);.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT flag like that:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```